# Construct meromorphic function that has single simple pole on $\Bbb{CP}^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, riemann-surfaces

I was trying to prove there exist a meromorphic function on the complex projective line $\Bbb{CP^1}$ which has single simple pole.(therefore it biholomorphic to the Riemann sphere).

In order to let it well defined, the map $f:\Bbb{CP}^1 \to \Bbb{C}$ needs to be homogeneous, for example $$f:\Bbb{CP^1} \to \Bbb{C}\\ [z_1:z_2]\mapsto z_1/z_2$$

however, this does not satisfy the requirement.I can prove it by first construct the coordiante function $z\mapsto z$ on the Riemann sphere, which has a single simple pole and single zero point.Then if we can find the biholomorphic map between $\Bbb{CP}^1$ and $S^2$ then precompose it with the corrdinate function $z\mapsto z$  gives a meromorphic function on $\Bbb{CP}^1$ that satisfies the requirement. Can we construct it directly?

Comment: Why do you think your map doesn't satisfy the requirements?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos  I don't understand $\Bbb{CP}^1$ very well, it seems the map above does not has isolated singularity, the singularity is a set of points that $z_2=0$

Comment: Oh Thank you it does not has isolated singularility at $\Bbb{C}^2$ however it we take quotient ,all the singular points collapse to a single point in $\Bbb{CP}^1$

Comment: All points where $z_2=0$ are the same, though, since $[z_1:z_2]=[\lambda z_1:\lambda z_2]$ for $\lambda\neq0$.

Comment: I see you found out yourself. Good!